# Can an SSD that holds a boot image for a Pi 4 boot any other ARM64 architecture machine?

Tags: 20.04, hardware, raspberrypi

Truly Noob question: A few months back, I set up a Raspberry Pi 4 8gb as an Ethereum 2.0 validator using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I formatted my [Samsung T5 SSD drive to boot the pi using this guide](https://medium.com/@zsmahi/make-ubuntu-server-20-04-boot-from-an-ssd-on-raspberry-pi-4-33f15c66acd4), and it's worked flawlessly. It successfully ran on the Medalla testnet, and I'm going to use the same rig on the mainnet, though some warn a pi is going to be underpowered if the network is struggling. I'm crossing my fingers, but if that turns out to be the case and I need to upgrade hardware fast, is there an alternative ARM64 rig that my SSD will boot, or is an Ubuntu Arm64 Pi build absolutely Pi hardware specific?

Comment: Should work with any Arm64.  How well will depend if specific drivers needed for other hardware attached.  Would google 'install ubuntu arm64 on (make and model)' to check.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. If you want to post it as an answer I'll accept it and mark this solved.